# how to delete a row in first position the sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

How to delete  a row in first position the sqlite in android
Now i am using this code for delete the row

```
public void delete(String id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{id});
   // db.execSQL(TABLE_CONTACTS , " ORDER BY " + KEY_ID + " ASC;");
    db.close();
}
```

But i want to delete the row in first position. Because KEY_ID will not be the same all the time when deletion occur

Comment: The first thing i would suggest is to make database writable then you can delete the data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use this method to delete first row

```
    public void deleteFirstRow()
{
    db.open();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null, null, null, null, null); 

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String rowId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)); 

            db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "=?",  new String[]{rowId});
           }
db.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a function which will return you the id of first row. Use this id in your delete function.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to got the data which is at first Position. Get data in a cursor move to first position extract the id and then call your method to delete that id from the Table. By this way you have always the data which is at first position. your query seems write to me.

Comment: just write the query for selecting the data. Which is `SELECT * FROM "your Table name"` and then you have all the data present to that table in your cursor. Then move to first position by the method `moveToFirst()` method  And then you can extract the id from that curor isnt it .

Comment: and please have a look on this tutorial by this way you will understand to use basics of database in android http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to look like this:

```
public void deleteFirstRow(String id) {
    int result;
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    // Find all records stored in the table in which you want to delete
    // first row
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null, null, null,
            null, null);

    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        result = db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "=?",
                mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));

    }

    Log.i("deleteFirstRow", "Deleted " + result + " rows.");

}
```

Note that `dbHelper` is the object of `SQLiteOpenHelper` defined as a member variable.